# Get values from array in order inside for

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array in react

```
const pallete = ['#5931B5', '#7842F5', '#2EABE3', '#F2711C']
```

I want to create a function that will return the first hex, and then the second...

```
getColor(){
   //What code should I have here?
   return COLOR
}
```

This is my main function

```
updateArray(data){
        const dataAux = data;
        for(var key in dataAux.datasets) {
            if (typeof dataAux.datasets[key].backgroundColor == 'undefined'){
               //I want here to take the values from the first array (pallete) and give dataAux.datasets[key]... the first color, then when he reads it again the second one...

                for(var i in pallete){
                    dataAux.datasets[key].backgroundColor = getColor(color????);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The const Data have an array of objects something like this:

```
{labels: [1, 2, 3], datasets: [{label: 'Undefined', pointStyle: 'line', borderColor: pallete[0],borderWidth: 3,yAxisID: "bar-y-axis",data: [1, 2, 3]},{label: 'Undefined',backgroundColor: pallete[1],pointStyle: 'line',borderColor: pallete[1],borderWidth: 3,yAxisID: "bar-y-axis",data: [2, 4, 6]}]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return the first, then the second" ?

Comment: The first value from the array, then the next value from array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to declare the other function to get the color. You can use the following code to get the color and set that as background.

```
getColor(index){
   //What code should I have here?
   return pallete[index];
}

updateArray(data){
            const dataAux = data;
            var i=0;
            for(var key in dataAux.datasets) {
                if (typeof dataAux.datasets[key].backgroundColor == 'undefined'){
                   //I want here to take the values from the first array (pallete) and give dataAux.datasets[key]... the first color, then when he reads it again the second one...
    
                   
                        dataAux.datasets[key].backgroundColor = getColor(i%4);
                       i++;
                    
    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That seems not to work.. the I its the number (0, 1, 2, 3)...

Comment: Hey I have edited the answer, please look into that.

Comment: Thats is working, but lets suppose I want it more flexible? that getColor(i%**4**) could be something like getColor(i%totalOfColors)?

Comment: Yeah, that could work perfectly. you can use getColor(i%pallete.length) directly. If this is helpful, please upvote too so that others can use this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an overkill, but you can create an object with "memory" to provide you with colors.

```
function ColorProvider(){
    var _this=this;

    _this.colors = ['#5931B5', '#7842F5', '#2EABE3', '#F2711C'];
    _this.currentIndex = 0;

    _this.getNext = function() {
        let returnedColor = _this.colors[_this.currentIndex];
        if(_this.currentIndex == _this.colors.length-1){
            _this.currentIndex = 0;
        } else {
            _this.currentIndex++;
        }
    }
}


let color = new ColorProvider();
dataAux.datasets[key].backgroundColor = getColor(color.getNext());
```

Excuse my archaic JavaScript practices, it's just a POC. I'm sure there is a more modern/slick to go around this, the point is having an object for it instead of primitives.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get each color on each call of function you can leverage the generator function functionality like below to get each color on each iteration of your loop:

```
const pallete = ['#5931B5', '#7842F5', '#2EABE3', '#F2711C']

function* getColor(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    yield arr[i]
  }
}

const iterator = getColor(pallete)

console.log(iterator.next()) // { value:  '#5931B5', done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()) // { value:  '#7842F5', done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()) // { value:  '#2EABE3', done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()) // { value:  '#F2711C', done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()) // { value:  undefined, done: true }
```

in your case, you can call the `iterator.next()` value inside of your loop until it reaches the `undefined` condition and then you need to break the loop!